# AngularJS + $resource + ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-resource

I am having trouble with one step in the following sequence:

1. Post data to a rest server and get a complete record in return.
2. Update web page with the new record.

I have a working $resource and issue my post in the controller using the following.

```
$scope.update = function(newRecord) {
    //use resource called apiClient to POST a record to API server
    apiClient.save(newRecord).$promise.then(function(response) {           
         //attempt to add new complete record to list on the web page
         $scope.existingRecords.push(response.data);
    });
};
```

However my ng-repeat list will NOT update to reflect the new entry. I can confirm that the array, $scope.existingRecords (which drives my ng-repeat), is getting the new record but no joy in the DOM.

I've heard about a few options but I've not had any luck...

```
$scope.update = function(newRecord) {
    //use resource called apiClient to POST a record to API server
    apiClient.save(newRecord).$promise.then(function(response) {           
         //attempt to add new complete record to list on the web page
         $scope.existingRecords.push(response.data);
         //let's try to force an update
         $scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

Gets me an error....

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Modify to get around the digest error...

```
....
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply();
});
....
```

Runs w/o errors but doesn't update ng-repeat either.

**Update**
Newly created records are added with:

```
$scope.existingRecords.push(response.data);
```

Firebug shows the pre-existing and new records slightly differently:

```
Resource { id="2", name="existing-record", more...}


Object { id="41", name="just posted via ajax", more...}
```

Not sure if it's matters, maybe I'm adding the new record to the model the wrong way?

Comment: I'm afraid I did not.  Soon after I gave up on Angular and drank the Ember kool-aid.

Comment: LOl. Ok, thanks. My immediate issue appears to have been a cache refresh issue. ng-repeat rendered correctly after a hard purge of browser and server caches.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you've tried `$scope.apply()`, but that should instead be `$scope.$apply();` Calling this after pushing `response.data` should ensure your view is updated.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo which I'll correct in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `$promise` of a `$resource` api call, the result will be pass directly into the `then()` function.

Therefore, you have to change `response.data` to just `data` like this:

```
$scope.update = function(newRecord) {
    // use resource called apiClient to POST a record to API server
    apiClient.save(newRecord).$promise.then(function(data) {           
        //attempt to add new complete record to list on the web page
        $scope.existingRecords.push(data);
    });
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The response I get form my api is formated as follows...    {"status":"OK","data":`code`{"id":"39","name":"test","imageUrl":null,"snippet":"droid","age":1}}  
           
I am getting the full reponse object into $promise.then.  So I only add the response.data portion to my model.  The new model record is getting added correctly, it just won't update ng-repeat.

Comment: Is there any duplicate item in the `existingRecords` list?

Comment: No duplicates,but I see that the newly added record looks slightly different.  Firebug shows a record as `Resource { id="2", name="MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122", snippet="The Next, Next Generatio...ndroid 3.0 (Honeycomb).", more...}`  for an existing record but my new record is....`Object { id="41", name="asdf asdf asdf", snippet="droid", more...}`

Comment: Please include the above detail in the question, it hard to see in comment.

Comment: I hate the comment system :)